# GoogleCredential.fromStream(JSON_FILE_AS_INPUTSTREAM) does not work

Tags: java, json, google-api

Using Google Developer Console I have downloaded a `JSON` file of my public/private Credentials for my Service Account:

```
{
  "private_key_id": "myPrivateKey",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\myPrivateKeyString\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "myClientEmail@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "myClientEmailId.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "type": "service_account"
}
```

They are stored on the classpath in a file called `serviceAccountCredentials.json`

When I try to execute the following code to return a `GoogleCredential` instance:

```
     InputStream credentialsJSON = MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("serviceAccountCredentials.json");
    JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    return GoogleCredential.fromStream(credentialsJSON ,httpTransport,JSON_FACTORY);
```

It blows up with the following stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no JSON input found
    at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:92)
    at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:49)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.startParsing(JsonParser.java:222)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:379)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:354)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:87)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:81)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.fromStream(GoogleCredential.java:250)
```

I am able to print the contents of the file to the console using the following code:

`System.out.println(IOUtils.toString(credentialsJSON));`

**Therefore I know that the `JSON` file is accessible and contains content.**

One therefore assumes that this API is fundamentally broken?

I favour a solution using JSON. I do not want to use a a `P12` file because:

1. I wish to supply my credentials from the classpath. `GoogleCredential.Builder` [does not provide a method which consumes an `InputStream`](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client/issues/857) (only `File`) so P12 is not an acceptable option:

[image]

2. Google implies in their UI for creating the credentials that `P12` is the legacy manner of authentication and that JSON should be used in the first instance:

[image: Image showing JSON is recommended]

Answer (score 0):

[@pongrad](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client/issues/979#issuecomment-157899802) has investigated this issue and produced code which illustrates that the API works correctly in isolation.

I recant this question as it is too isolated (suspect Maven transient dependency issue in the context of my other project dependencies).

Answer (score 0):

For every change, restart IDE. This was the mistake I was making, not restarting the IDE after attempting the different solutions. My filename.json file is in the resource folder.

```
GoogleCredentials googleCredentials = GoogleCredentials
.fromStream(new ClassPathResource("your file.json")
.getInputStream());
```